# Cabal missing packages

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I try to install cabal with the command on terminal

```
cabal install cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
Building hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
Failed to install hackage-security-0.5.2.2
Build log ( /Users/developer/.cabal/logs/hackage-security-0.5.2.2.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/2x/t_2cl03x2092dkzvc702d7lc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-586/hackage-security-0.5.2.2'
Configuring hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
Building hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
Preprocessing library hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
[ 1 of 42] Compiling Prelude          ( src/Prelude.hs, dist/build/Prelude.o )
[ 2 of 42] Compiling Text.JSON.Canonical ( src/Text/JSON/Canonical.hs, dist/build/Text/JSON/Canonical.o )
Failed to load interface for ‘Data.Text’
There are files missing in the ‘text-1.2.2.1’ package,
try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/2x/t_2cl03x2092dkzvc702d7lc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-586/hackage-security-0.5.2.2'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.24.0.2 depends on hackage-security-0.5.2.2 which failed to
install.
hackage-security-0.5.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I am using `macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1`. The Haskell installation package is from https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html. The installation was successful.

When I try to install `cabal install ghc-mod` I've got following error:

```
cabal install ghc-mod
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring haskell-src-exts-1.18.2...
Building haskell-src-exts-1.18.2...
Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.18.2
Build log ( /Users/developer/.cabal/logs/haskell-src-exts-1.18.2.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/2x/t_2cl03x2092dkzvc702d7lc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-713/haskell-src-exts-1.18.2'
Configuring haskell-src-exts-1.18.2...
Building haskell-src-exts-1.18.2...
Preprocessing library haskell-src-exts-1.18.2...
[ 1 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Syntax.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Syntax.o )
[ 2 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.SrcLoc ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/SrcLoc.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/SrcLoc.o )
[ 3 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.ParseSyntax ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/ParseSyntax.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/ParseSyntax.o )
[ 4 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Pretty ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Pretty.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Pretty.o )
[ 5 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Fixity ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Fixity.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Fixity.o )
[ 6 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Extension ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Extension.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Extension.o )
[ 7 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.ExtScheme ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/ExtScheme.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/ExtScheme.o )
[ 8 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Comments ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Comments.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Comments.o )
[ 9 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.ExactPrint ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/ExactPrint.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/ExactPrint.o )
[10 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.ParseMonad ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/ParseMonad.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/ParseMonad.o )
[11 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.InternalLexer ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/InternalLexer.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/InternalLexer.o )
[12 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Lexer ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Lexer.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Lexer.o )
[13 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.ParseUtils ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/ParseUtils.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/ParseUtils.o )
[14 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.InternalParser ( dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/InternalParser.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/InternalParser.o )
[15 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Parser.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Parser.o )
[16 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts.Build ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts/Build.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts/Build.o )
[17 of 17] Compiling Language.Haskell.Exts ( src/Language/Haskell/Exts.hs, dist/build/Language/Haskell/Exts.o )

src/Language/Haskell/Exts.hs:55:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Language.Preprocessor.Unlit’
    There are files missing in the ‘cpphs-1.20.2’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/2x/t_2cl03x2092dkzvc702d7lc0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-713/haskell-src-exts-1.18.2'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghc-mod-5.7.0.0 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.18.2 which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.18.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
hlint-1.9.40 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.18.2 which failed to install.
```

The following cabal version is installed:

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

I also tried to run `ghc-pkg check` and got a lot of package problems, few examples:

```
There are problems in package monad-journal-0.7.2:
  Warning: library-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/monad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: dynamic-library-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Users/developer/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/monad-journal-0.7.2/html/monad-journal.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
  Warning: haddock-html: /Users/developer/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/monad-journal-0.7.2/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/monad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Journal.hi","Control/Monad/Journal.p_hi","Control/Monad/Journal.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Journal/Class.hi","Control/Monad/Journal/Class.p_hi","Control/Monad/Journal/Class.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Trans/Journal.hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Journal.p_hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Journal.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["libHSmonad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP.a","libHSmonad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP.p_a","libHSmonad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP-ghc8.0.2.so","libHSmonad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP-ghc8.0.2.dylib","HSmonad-journal-0.7.2-6mtwu36per6DTorptNDDzP-ghc8.0.2.dll"] on library path
There are problems in package either-4.4.1.1:
  Warning: library-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/either-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: dynamic-library-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Users/developer/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/either-4.4.1.1/html/either.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
  Warning: haddock-html: /Users/developer/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/either-4.4.1.1/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/either-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Trans/Either.hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Either.p_hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Either.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Data/Either/Combinators.hi","Data/Either/Combinators.p_hi","Data/Either/Combinators.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Data/Either/Validation.hi","Data/Either/Validation.p_hi","Data/Either/Validation.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["libHSeither-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL.a","libHSeither-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL.p_a","libHSeither-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL-ghc8.0.2.so","libHSeither-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL-ghc8.0.2.dylib","HSeither-4.4.1.1-CrzaYJSOcIXAyUkEE7mRiL-ghc8.0.2.dll"] on library path
There are problems in package free-4.12.4:
  Warning: library-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/free-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: dynamic-library-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Users/developer/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/free-4.12.4/html/free.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
  Warning: haddock-html: /Users/developer/.cabal/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/free-4.12.4/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /Users/developer/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.0.2/free-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  cannot find any of ["Control/Applicative/Free.hi","Control/Applicative/Free.p_hi","Control/Applicative/Free.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Applicative/Free/Final.hi","Control/Applicative/Free/Final.p_hi","Control/Applicative/Free/Final.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Applicative/Trans/Free.hi","Control/Applicative/Trans/Free.p_hi","Control/Applicative/Trans/Free.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Alternative/Free.hi","Control/Alternative/Free.p_hi","Control/Alternative/Free.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Alternative/Free/Final.hi","Control/Alternative/Free/Final.p_hi","Control/Alternative/Free/Final.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Comonad/Cofree.hi","Control/Comonad/Cofree.p_hi","Control/Comonad/Cofree.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Comonad/Cofree/Class.hi","Control/Comonad/Cofree/Class.p_hi","Control/Comonad/Cofree/Class.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Comonad/Trans/Cofree.hi","Control/Comonad/Trans/Cofree.p_hi","Control/Comonad/Trans/Cofree.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Comonad/Trans/Coiter.hi","Control/Comonad/Trans/Coiter.p_hi","Control/Comonad/Trans/Coiter.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Free.hi","Control/Monad/Free.p_hi","Control/Monad/Free.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Free/Church.hi","Control/Monad/Free/Church.p_hi","Control/Monad/Free/Church.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Free/Class.hi","Control/Monad/Free/Class.p_hi","Control/Monad/Free/Class.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Free/TH.hi","Control/Monad/Free/TH.p_hi","Control/Monad/Free/TH.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Trans/Free.hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Free.p_hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Free.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Trans/Free/Church.hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Free/Church.p_hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Free/Church.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["Control/Monad/Trans/Iter.hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Iter.p_hi","Control/Monad/Trans/Iter.dyn_hi"]
  cannot find any of ["libHSfree-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM.a","libHSfree-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM.p_a","libHSfree-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM-ghc8.0.2.so","libHSfree-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM-ghc8.0.2.dylib","HSfree-4.12.4-Hbi0FikbXDW7eNkrPW79mM-ghc8.0.2.dll"] on library path
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not using stack?

Comment: What is stack exactly? And what is the difference?

Comment: stack is [this](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases), and there's [some differences](https://www.google.com/?#q=cabal+stack), tl;dr. if you didn't know stack, just use stack.

Comment: What is haskell stack exactly?

Comment: `cabal` is the package description library. `cabal-install` is the build & automation tool which utilize cabal. `stack` is somewhat like dependency manager, which eliminates the problem called [cabal hell](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/11/solving-cabal-hell).

Comment: Where can I find a tutorial to intall ghc?

Comment: There's nothing difficult. I've never used Mac, but you may follow [this](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#macos). If installation is successful, then maybe all you need to do is `stack install ghc-mod`. If you just need the ghc, run `stack setup && stack exec ghci`.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out tonight. Thanks

Comment: I am planing to https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell as IDE, it works well with stack?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you. I have once tried that too, but it didn't work as I thought. It might be because of the platform problem, but I don't know the reason anyway.